# How Bind Image and text in a datagridview column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

For my application I need to put Icon and Text in the same datagridview column.

Comment: I added proper tags. If it is wrong please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707061 - this seems to be the answer for your problem.